# Leniency for depression on Shabbat?

Tags: shabbat, choleh-sick, leniencies

The Talmud says:

> "הַמְכַבֶּה אֶת הַנֵּר מִפְּנֵי שֶׁהוּא מִתְיָרֵא מִפְּנֵי גּוֹיִם וּמִפְּנֵי לִיסְטִים, מִפְּנֵי רוּחַ רָעָה, מִפְּנֵי הַחוֹלֶה שֶׁיִּישַׁן — פָּטוּר."
> "One who extinguishes a lamp on Shabbat because he is afraid... of an evil spirit, [Sefaria: i.e., he is depressed and prefers sitting in the dark] is not liable". [[Shabbat 29b](https://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.29b.12?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)]

Is this leniency fleshed out a bit anywhere?

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding. this isn't a leniency for depression. Any reason for extinguisging the lamp that isn't constructive to the lamp is not a biblical prohibition.

Comment: Please explain "constructive to the lamp".

Comment: Like in a case where he extinguishes the flame in order to spare the lamp, spare the oil, or spare the wick. I'm not going to say that my Enlglish phraseology is definitive, but the principles of prohibited labor on shabbat having to be constructive, done in a normal fashion, for the intended purpose etc. are well documented elsewhere

Comment: You could extinguish the flame because you prefer it dark (e.g., to go to sleep) **AND** "to spare the lamp, spare the oil, or spare the wick".   Allowed?

Comment: Definitely not allowed!!! The only question here is if you are exempt from biblical punishment. You could also plow both to help the ground accept seeds and because you like the way freshly plowed fields look. I can't imagine why that wouldn't be biblically forbidden too.

Comment: Acc. to Rambam - Patur only means exempt from punishment, not that the action is allowed. Because we talk about indirect intentions, they will all be exempt. The Mishnah provides examples of such unintentional transgressing.

Comment: @doubleAA --- just to be clear: Are you saying it's OK to turn unneeded lights and appliances off during Shabbat if your sole purpose is to lower your electricity bill?

Comment: @Maurice I'm saying that wouldn't get a biblical punishment. It's still quite forbidden rabbinically, just like writing with your non-dominant hand.

Answer (score 1):

In the specific context of this Mishna, the Gemara explains that all the permitted cases listed are cases where there is danger to one's life. In these cases, putting out the lamp is completely permitted. (The term "not liable" is used only as  a contrast to the end of the mishna's case where one is liable to the consequences of trangressing.) Therefore the case of ruach ra'ah would be a case where there is a danger of the melancholia causing a fatal outcome of some sort. (Suicide, or some other irrational behavior that would cause danger.)
Cases of depression that are *Clearly* not likely to cause fatal harm would not fall under this permit.

Shalom U'Vrachah
JS

Comment: Do you have a source for this estimation of the effects of mental illness?

Comment: @pcoz I'm not sure what you are seeking. Different illnesses have different effects.

Comment: But if there is a danger to life, is it even necessary to say it is permitted?  Also, you never know (back then or now) when mental illness may turn fatal -- so is this a blank check to violate Shabbat as you deem necessary?

Comment: @DoubleAA As opposed to a medical condition, mental illness is a long term disorder with an unclear prognosis. Therefore it is not valid to say that if on this Shabbos there is no clear need to be *mechalel Shabbos* that it would be prohibited to do so for the sake of someone who suffers from depression etc. I would imagine that just as regarding women eating on Yom Kippur after childbirth etc. we ask the opinion of a medical professional if there is danger to life, so too in the case of a psychological complaint it would be appropriate to consult with a professional.

Comment: @pcoz I don't understand, who said you don't consult a professional and evaluate every case on its own merits?

Comment: @DoubleAA So we are saying the same thing. All I am adding is that you should not only consider if there is a *sakanah* on that Shabbos, you have to take the long term picture into account.